# Grouping users under parent user

Tags: users, user-roles, user-meta

What it needs to be like:

- one "super user" with user role *company*
- normal users with user role *employee*

---

1. I don't want "super user" to be able to have more capabilities, especially admin-like capabilities.
2. I don't want to use custom post to emulate *company* because `postmeta` table is already getting too big compared to the rest. Also I need both to be able to login and that "super user" can manage its users in front-end.
3. Normal users should be query-able by "super user" *a.k.a* query all users who are employees in that specific company.

**How to make that kind of connection between user and "super user"?** Obviously `usermeta` is the way to go but how to approach this? I don't need a huge code that works, I need *an idea* how it would work.

Comment: This strikes me as  "too broad" and kinda "work for me for free".

Comment: @s_ha_dum **No, no..** I only need an idea how to make a connection between 2 user roles / users where 1 is superior and "acts as a group". I've searched for this solution for all these months I've developed my site but nothing: no plugins, no tutorials, not even search results in Google. I really don't want to use custom post.

Comment: You have an idea-- `usermeta`. Users aren't built to "nest" like categories do, so what you are asking is "how do I alter the basic structure of WordPress Users/Roles". That is pretty broad.

Comment: How would it look like? That every normal user have `usermeta` about super user ID and vice versa? Then use this ID to query? That's the problem, building up this logic is killing me. Coding it.. I can already handle that.

Comment: Well that's the problem. It is a weird, complicated thing to do with many, many implications. You may even be better off with a dedicated table to handle the relationships, but again, many many implications some of which may not be immediately obvious.

Comment: Okay. I'll look into it even more, try to figure out the logic behind that, experiment with different solutions and post the answer myself if I find one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33109/discussion-between-s-ha-dum-and-n00b).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Roles

First of all you need to register the 2 roles, look at [`add_role`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_role/).

When you register the role, you are free to assign any capability you want.

Only be careful to add the roles when your theme / plugin is activated and possibly remove them (see [`remove_role`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_role/)) when it is disabled.

---

## Meta Data

You can do the association using a meta entry like `company_employees` that stores an array of user IDs. You can associate some custom function to get / set employees to a company user.

#### Get Employees of a Company

Example code for a function that return an array of employees given an user:

```
function getEmployees(\WP_User $user) {
  // if the user has not the role "company_role" can't have employees
  if ( ! in_array('company_role', $user->roles, true) ) {
    return array();
  }
  $meta = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'company_employees', true);
  if (empty($meta)) {
    return array();
  }

  $query = new WP_User_Query(array(
    'role'    => 'employee_role',
    'include' => (array) $meta
  ));

  return $query->results;
}
```

#### Assign Employee to a Company

In the same way you can write a function to assign an employee to a company user:

```
function assignToCompany(\WP_User $employee, \WP_User $company) {
  // if the company user has not the role "company_role" can't have employees
  if ( ! in_array('company_role', $company->roles, true) ) {
     return false;
  }
  // if the employee user has not the role "employee_role" can't be assigned
  if ( ! in_array('employee_role', $employee->roles, true) ) {
     return false;
  }
  // get current employees
  $employees = get_user_meta($company->ID, 'company_employees', true);
  is_empty($employees) and $employees = array();
  // add employee and update
  $employees[] = $employee->ID;
  $update = update_user_meta($company->ID, 'company_employees', $employees);

  return (int) $update > 0;
}
```

---

### UI

Of course, you need some sort of UI to assign employees to users. If an employee may have only one company, you can show a dropdown menu in the user edit page where you list all the companies and, on save, you can leverage the function above to store the employee in the company user meta.

To do that:

- look at [`edit_user_profile`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_user_profile/) hook to print the dropdown menu. Be sure to show the menu only to users that are allowed to edit the employee company
- look at [`edit_user_profile_update`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_user_profile_update/) hook to save the company in the meta field. Be sure to proceed with save only if current user is allowed to edit the employee company
- be sure to also add a [nonce field](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) when you print the dropdown menu, and verify it before proceed with save. See [`wp_nonce_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nonce_field/) and [`wp_verify_nonce()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_verify_nonce/)

---

## Final Touches

#### Company User Admin UI

You can add the list of the employees currently assigned to a company user in the user edit page.

Make it editable is a bonus.

#### Utility functions

You can add a couple of utility functions like `isEmployee()`, `isCompany()` that accept an user object ot id and return a true / false if the user has the related role.

`isEmployee` might also accept an optional param with a company user, and return true only if the user is an employee of that specific company.

#### Custom Capability

It may be a good idea to introduce a custom capability `'assign_employee'` that you can assign to administrators, and to any other role you want to be able to assign employees users to company users. This could be useful when you need to show rthe company dropdown and when you have to save the company meta.

With this capability in place you can check if an user is allowed to do that using `current_user_can('assign_employee')`.

To assign a custom capability to an existent role, have a look to [`WP_Roles::add_cap()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_roles/add_cap/).

If you decide to do this, remember to remove the capability when the plugin / theme is disabled.

#### Frontend Company Page

Don't know if you need it, but you can create a "company page" in frontend, using a custom [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) and a [custom endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) to show the user company description and a list of all employees